# Percentage Output printing out 0

Tags: java, methods, constructor

I am new to Java, and I am trying to get a Field Goal percentage calculation, and the output keeps giving me 0. Not sure if it has something to do with my constructor, or if it is not pulling the correct info out of my array.

```
public Player(String newName, int newnumMade, int newnumAttempt)
    {
        name = newName;
        
        numAttempt = newnumAttempt;
        numMade = newnumMade;
        
        if(newnumAttempt < newnumMade)
        {
            numMade = newnumAttempt;
            numAttempt = newnumMade;
        }
        else 
        {
            numAttempt = newnumAttempt;
            numMade = newnumMade;
        }
    }
```

```
public double getfgPercentage()
    {
        
         if(numAttempt > 0)
        {
            double first = (double)numMade / numAttempt;
            fgPercentage = first * 100;
        }
        return fgPercentage;
    }
```

I understand that int division always gives an int so I converted one of my ints into a double. Ive tested out multiple ways adding two numbers just to see if it would work, but the output is constantly giving me 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgPercentage = numMade * 100 / numAttempt;
```

Otherwise, your code is not working as expected, because you cast numMade into double while still dividing it by the integer numAttempt.

Comment: It is still giving me 0.00. I’ve tried multiple ways including the one you just mentioned, unless something is wrong somewhere where I would not expect to look.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of Things:

Firstly, make sure you get your question precise. You are mentioning an array with no array to be found anywhere, you are not showing us how you are calling the Constructor etc.

That being said, your Constructor looks fine, other than that there are two unnecessary assignments in it, and you can give the Parameters of the Constructor the same names as the fields in your Class, like so:

```
public Player(String name, int numMade, int numAttempt) {
        this.name = name;
        if (numAttempt < numMade) {
            this.numMade = numAttempt;
            this.numAttempt = numMade;
        } else {
            this.numAttempt = numAttempt;
            this.numMade = numMade;
        }
    }
```

Then, I recommend you change your `calculateFieldGoalPercentage()` method to this:

```
  public double calculateFieldGoalPercentage() {
        if (numAttempt > 0) {
            return ((double) numMade / numAttempt) * 100;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I would not have the assignment of the variable in an if clause and then return the field outside of it like you are currently doing, as that can lead to returning null, because the variable has never been instantiated.

Finally, you can now use this Class in your main Method like so:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player[] team = {new Player("Tony", 3, 17),
                new Player("Peter", 0, 12), new Player("Mary", 2, 3)};

        for (Player p : team) {
            p.printData();
        }
    }
```

This example will give you the output:

```
Name : Tony
Field Goals Made : 3
Fields Goals Attempted : 17
Field Goal Percentage :  17.65
Effectiveness : 17.647058823529413
____________________________________________
Name : Peter
Field Goals Made : 0
Fields Goals Attempted : 12
Field Goal Percentage :  0.00
Effectiveness : 0.0
____________________________________________
Name : Mary
Field Goals Made : 2
Fields Goals Attempted : 3
Field Goal Percentage :  66.67
Effectiveness : 66.66666666666666
____________________________________________
```

**EDIT**

The problem is, that you are never calling the function that calculates the field `fieldGoalPercentage`. Here is what you need to change, alongside the above:

```
public void printData() {
        System.out.println("Name : " + name);
        System.out.println("Field Goals Made : " + numMade);
        System.out.println("Fields Goals Attempted : " + numAttempt);
        System.out.printf("%8s %.2f%n", "Field Goal Percentage : ", calculateFieldGoalPercentage());
        System.out.println("Effectiveness : " + calculateFieldGoalPercentage());
        System.out.println("____________________________________________");
    }
```

Comment: Correct, perhaps I should have been more clear. For my program, this getPercentage method is supposed to go into a printInfo method in my class. Then, when I pull this over to my main class for example, player[1].printInfo; it is supposed to pull all that info. I am not specifically calling that method into the main class, but instead calling the bigger printInfo to bring me all variables that need to be printed.

Comment: public void printData()
 { 
  System.out.println("Name : " + name);
  System.out.println("Field Goals Made : " + numMade);
  System.out.println("Fields Goals Attempted : " + numAttempt);
  System.out.printf("%8s %.2f%n", "Field Goal Percentage : ", fgPercentage);
  System.out.println("Effectiveness : " + effective);
  System.out.println("____________________________________________");
 }

Comment: There is the printInfo method that is needed. team[0] = new Player("Jill", 5, 9);
 team[1] = new Player("Sallie", 0, 3);
 team[2] = new Player("Mary", 4, 7);
 team[3] = new Player("Sue", 4, 7);

Comment: Along with the array of players

Comment: I will edit my answer with the new info.

Comment: @marior21 Do not reply with code snippets. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74370544/edit) your question instead.